# Secure Rest API using oauth

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

We want to secure our api using OAuth.

Our server exposes functionalities through APIs. Separate UI applications consume these APIs. 
Users use these UI application to access their resources. Since there are only two systems (client and server) involved,
we would like to have 2 legged authorization flow instead of 3legged with redirections. Also we would like have 
separate UI (client) application verification once and use this verification code to perform user login and get access token.

Currently we are evaluating spring security framework. Most of spring security tutorials/article talks about 3-legged oAuth with bearer token approach. 
I’m not sure if it supports request singing and above mentioned required process. Is there any other open source framework we can use?

Comment: The OAuth2 spec appears to be compatible with your requirements. But to get a helpful response on stackoverflow you need to phrase the question more precisely. What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Thanks Dave Syer.Our server exposes functionalities though APIs. Separate UI applications consume these APIs.Users use these UI application to access their resources. Since there are only two systems (client and server) involved,we would like to have 2 legged authorization flow instead of 3legged with redirections.

Comment: Also we would like have separate UI (client) application verification once and use this verification code to perform user login and get access token.Currently we are evaluating spring security framework. Most of spring security tutorials/article talks about 3-legged oAuth with bearer token approach. I’m not sure if it supports request singing and above mentioned required process. Is there any other open source framework we can use?

Comment: Request signing is orthogonal to authentication. You could add it to a Spring app (e.g. using the RSA utilities in spring-security-jwt), but it isn't a core feature. And your flow is (IMO) ideally 3-legged because you have a browser/user, so OAuth2 is still a a good fit for the use case.

Comment: Thanks Dave Syer for your valuable feedback.

Our server is a headless application and exposes functionality through API that includes login functionality and user management API(like user onboarding). Client application(web client) which will have login page/UI to provide login functionality so user would use client login UI(browser) to authenticate and access the resources. Also our server doesn’t support any redirections to the client  application as it is exposes bunch of services through  API .  So in this case what would be the suitable flow for us